# Button displays only last note in my note taker app

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, event-listener

```js
const adder = document.querySelector('.adder')
const gridcont = document.querySelector('.gridbox') 
const text = document.querySelector('p')
const button = document.querySelector('.button') 
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup-wrapper')
const popuptext = document.querySelector('.popup-content')
const close = document.querySelector('.popup-close')
const notecard = document.querySelector('.card')
const notetext = document.querySelector('.card-text')
const pi = document.querySelector('p')
let counter = 0;
let html;
let note;
let html2


/*close.addEventListener('click', e =>{
  popup.style.display ='none'
}) */


popup.addEventListener('click', e=>{
  popup.style.display ='none'
})



const template = note =>{
   html = `<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Note ${counter}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">${note}</p>
    <button class="button" type="button">view detail</button>
  </div>
</div>`
 
gridcont.innerHTML += html
}

adder.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
  e.preventDefault()
  note = adder.add.value
  

  if(note.length){
    counter++
    template(note)
    adder.reset()
  }
})

gridcont.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    if(e.target.classList.contains('button')){
         popup.style.display = 'block'
         popuptext.innerHTML = html
    }
  });
```

```css
.card{
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;


}
.form-control{
  max-width: 500px;
}
.blu{
  color: blue;
}

.gridbox{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.button{
  color:white;
  background-color: rgb(41, 41, 241);
  border-color: rgb(41, 41, 241);;
}

  .card-text{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 200px;
  }


.popup-wrapper{
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.popup{
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.popup-close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-text-show{
  overflow: unset;
  text-overflow: unset;
  max-width: 200px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Note taker</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="head text-center">
      <header>
         <h1>Note taker app</h1>
         <h8 class="blu">add note:</p>
      </header>
      <form class="adder">
         <input class="form-control m-auto" type="text" name="add"  placeholder="Enter your note here">
      </form>
   </div>
   <div class="gridbox">



  </div>
  <div class="popup-wrapper">
   <div class="popup">
      <div class="popup-close">x</div>
      <div class="popup-content">
      <h5 class="card-title"> </h5>
      <p class="card-text">   </p>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

im trying to make note taker app and each time i add the note and click the view detail button
it shows me only the content of  last item added regardless of which one i  press i dont know how to write with loop or forEach method i tried it but i failed can anyone explain what to do here im a begginer JS

```
const adder = document.querySelector('.adder')
const gridcont = document.querySelector('.gridbox') 
const text = document.querySelector('p')
const button = document.querySelector('.button') 
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup-wrapper')
const popuptext = document.querySelector('.popup-content')
const close = document.querySelector('.popup-close')
const notecard = document.querySelector('.card')
const notetext = document.querySelector('.card-text')
const pi = document.querySelector('p')
let counter = 0;
let html;
let note;
let html2


/*close.addEventListener('click', e =>{
  popup.style.display ='none'
}) */


popup.addEventListener('click', e=>{
  popup.style.display ='none'
})



const template = note =>{
   html = `<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Note ${counter}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">${note}</p>
    <button class="button" type="button">view detail</button>
  </div>
</div>`
 
gridcont.innerHTML += html
}

adder.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
  e.preventDefault()
  note = adder.add.value
  

  if(note.length){
    counter++
    template(note)
    adder.reset()
  }
})

gridcont.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    if(e.target.classList.contains('button')){
         popup.style.display = 'block'
         popuptext.innerHTML = html
    }
  });
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Note taker</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="head text-center">
      <header>
         <h1>Note taker app</h1>
         <h8 class="blu">add note:</p>
      </header>
      <form class="adder">
         <input class="form-control m-auto" type="text" name="add"  placeholder="Enter your note here">
      </form>
   </div>
   <div class="gridbox">



  </div>
  <div class="popup-wrapper">
   <div class="popup">
      <div class="popup-close">x</div>
      <div class="popup-content">
      <h5 class="card-title"> </h5>
      <p class="card-text">   </p>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont really know many methods so i just use one way im stuck on this project for 4 days
CSS

```
.card{
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;


}
.form-control{
  max-width: 500px;
}
.blu{
  color: blue;
}

.gridbox{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.button{
  color:white;
  background-color: rgb(41, 41, 241);
  border-color: rgb(41, 41, 241);;
}

  .card-text{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 200px;
  }


.popup-wrapper{
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.popup{
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.popup-close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-text-show{
  overflow: unset;
  text-overflow: unset;
  max-width: 200px;

}
```

Comment: 'popuptext.innerHTML = html'
you forced that because in addEventListener you didn't load that HTML content dynamically and for every click on a different button it will show the same content.

Comment: How can i load it in listener dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

On `popuptext.innerHTML = html` line you are making the mistake, so what is happening is you are setting the innerHTML of popuptext as variable html, so this line tries find **html** variable and goes to part of this code,

```
const template = note =>{
  html = `<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Note ${counter}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">${note}</p>
    <button class="button" type="button">view detail</button>
    </div>
  </div>`

  gridcont.innerHTML += html
}
```

and then it finds the HTML variable here, however the value of this html variable will be whatever you have set it to earlier, so if you add three notes then the value of the html variable will be innerhtml of the latest/last note that you added.
To fix that I have made a change as `popuptext.innerHTML = e.target.parentElement.innerHTML`, this line makes sure that whatever element you are clicking that element's associated innerhtml is added to the popup.

```js
const adder = document.querySelector('.adder')
const gridcont = document.querySelector('.gridbox') 
const text = document.querySelector('p')
const button = document.querySelector('.button') 
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup-wrapper')
const popuptext = document.querySelector('.popup-content')
const close = document.querySelector('.popup-close')
const notecard = document.querySelector('.card')
const notetext = document.querySelector('.card-text')
const pi = document.querySelector('p')
let counter = 0;
let html;
let note;
let html2


/*close.addEventListener('click', e =>{
  popup.style.display ='none'
}) */


popup.addEventListener('click', e=>{
  popup.style.display ='none'
})



const template = note =>{
    
   html = `<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Note ${counter}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">${note.substring(0,6)}...<span class="only-popup">${note}</span></p>
    <button class="button" type="button">view detail</button>
  </div>
</div>`
 
gridcont.innerHTML += html
}

adder.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
  e.preventDefault()
  note = adder.add.value
  

  if(note.length){
    counter++
    template(note)
    adder.reset()
  }
})

gridcont.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    if(e.target.classList.contains('button')){
         popup.style.display = 'block'
         let temp = `<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.card-title').innerText}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">${e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.only-popup').innerText}</p>
    <button class="button" type="button">view detail</button>
  </div>
</div>`
         popuptext.innerHTML = temp
    }
  });
```

```css
.card{
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;


}
.form-control{
  max-width: 500px;
}
.blu{
  color: blue;
}

.gridbox{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.button{
  color:white;
  background-color: rgb(41, 41, 241);
  border-color: rgb(41, 41, 241);;
}

  .card-text{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 200px;
  }


.popup-wrapper{
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.popup{
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

.popup-close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.only-popup{
  display:none;
}
.card-text-show{
  overflow: unset;
  text-overflow: unset;
  max-width: 200px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Note taker</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="head text-center">
      <header>
         <h1>Note taker app</h1>
         <h8 class="blu">add note:</p>
      </header>
      <form class="adder">
         <input class="form-control m-auto" type="text" name="add"  placeholder="Enter your note here">
      </form>
   </div>
   <div class="gridbox">



  </div>
  <div class="popup-wrapper">
   <div class="popup">
      <div class="popup-close">x</div>
      <div class="popup-content">
      <h5 class="card-title"> </h5>
      <p class="card-text">   </p>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much for this i forgot to mention my one more problem so when the text is long it needs to be   covered and "..." must be displayed and so this view detail button should expand the text can is this the right way of doing it or im going in completely different direction? thank you again :)

Comment: No you are not going in different direction my brother, let me edit the post a little to achieve what you want, is there any specific length for text to truncate i.e if a string length exceeds a certain number then add ... and show full text in popup. is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: it doesnt really matter i just need to make sure that at some point text is hidden and then i must expand it with the button and reveal the whole text in a popup

Comment: I have updated the code and its working the way you want it work

Comment: woah that is such a nice trick @soraku02